Showing $\dim(A/I) + \operatorname{ht} I \leq \dim(A)$
Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $A \not= 0$. Then prove $\dim(A/I) + \operatorname{ht}I \leq \dim(A)$ for any ideal $I$ of $A$.
The definition of $\operatorname{ht} I$ is $\inf \{\operatorname{ht}(p) \mid I \subset p \}$. We can find a chain of primes
$$
p_0 \subset p_1 \subset \dots 
$$
whose length is $\dim(A/I)$, between $I$ and $A$. But $\operatorname{ht} (p_0)$ may not be $\operatorname{ht}\ I$.
Then we have $\dim(A/I) + \operatorname{ht} I \leq \dim(A/I) + \operatorname{ht} p_0 \leq \dim A$.
The last inequalities come from the definition of $\dim A$ and there is a chain of primes in $p_0$ with length $\operatorname{ht} p_0$.
Is this proof correct?

Careful; $I \subset \mathfrak{p}_0 \subset \cdots$ is not necessarily a chain of primes if $I$ is not prime. If $I$ is prime, then clearly the unique minimal prime over $I$ is itself.

I don't think you've completed the proof. Why is $\dim A/I + \operatorname{ht} p_0 \le \dim A$?

Proof
The definition of $\operatorname{ht} I$ is $\inf \{\operatorname{ht}(p) \mid I \subset p \}$. We can find a chain of primes
$$
p_0 \subset p_1 \subset \dots 
$$
whose length is $\dim(A/I)$, between $I$ and $A$. But $\operatorname{ht} (p_0)$ may not be $\operatorname{ht}\ I$.
Then we have $\dim(A/I) + \operatorname{ht} I \leq \dim(A/I) + \operatorname{ht} p_0 \leq \dim A$.
The last inequalities come from the definition of $\dim A$ and there is a chain of primes in $p_0$ with length $\operatorname{ht} p_0$.
